# css3 style rotate in ie,do anyone know how to make it happen?

Tags: css, rotation

i know in ie i could use "filter:" thing to do rotate,but the rotate in ies  is not rotate from the element center.

is there a way to simulate the css3 style rotate in ies?`enter code here`

ps:i did not desribe it properly.
i want a function ,not a one time compute.

like 
`$('div').click(rotate($(this),(i++)*Math.PI*1/6);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give this a go: [IE's CSS3 Transforms Translator](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/), I believe it mentions how to address the issue you mention.